# Implement Single SignOn with Identity Server 4

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver4

Given an Identity Server 4, can we implement a Single SignOn being used by different applications with a single user authentication server?

If so, how can we do that? Any reference material available for the same?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there is nothing special you have to do to enable single sign-on. It's available by default, but not for all scenarios.

In order to make SSO work there is only one rule:

*The user has to login on the IdentityServer website, because that's where the SSO cookie has to be placed.*

SSO is not available for [grant types](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html) that do not require the user to login on the IdentityServer website.

---

How it works:

A user visits webapp1, hits the login button and is redirected to the IdentityServer website in order to login. IdentityServer will scan for the SSO cookie but will not find it since this is the first time and the user isn't authenticated yet.

After succesful login, the SSO cookie is stored (on the IdentityServer website) and an authenticated user is returned to webapp1.

The user then visits webapp2. As long as the user is not required to authenticate the user will be an anonymous visitor.

Authentication is required when the user clicks on the login button or visits a secured page (e.g. secured by the `[Authorize]` attribute). That triggers the authentication flow which redirects the user to the IdentityServer website.

Again IdentityServer will scan for the SSO cookie, but this time it's found. Being already authenticated, the user isn't required to login again but is instead returned to the website as *authenticated user*.

Please note that the client can overrule the SSO cookie by setting the [prompt=login](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html?highlight=prompt) parameter.

Also note that cookies are not cross-browser. Visiting webapp2 *using a different browser* will require the user to login again because the SSO cookie isn't available for this browser.

Comment: Question: the only way I got SSO to work (I think) was to add multiple RedirectIds to a single Client in the Identity Server config. Is that how it is meant to be done, or is it possible to use separate Clients? When I do the latter, I keep getting redirected to the Consent page for the different client. Obviously, if they are all the same client, no such redirect. So, it using the RedirectUris collection the way to do SSO? Cheers

Comment: @onefootswill Normally there is only one instance of a client where one redirect url suffices. You can use the same client id for multiple instances, in which case you can add a redirect url for each instance. Please note, the redirect url is used for verification in order to prevent login from a fake client. Consent is not related to the redirect urls. Consent is stored in the PersistedGrants table per clientid. Using a different clientid requires another consent from the user.

Comment: Thanks. I realized last night that I don't even need a consent screen. It is just not a requirement and we aren't giving 3rd party apps access to anything. It is just our apps. When you remove the consent screen, you can get an SSO experience (in my testing so far) even when you use a separate client config for each client. So, I have gone back to using separate client configs for separate clients. So far so good 

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, that is what IdentityServer4 is used for (SSO & Authentication).
There is [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html) and some [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples).

Comment: nothing in the documentation or samples shows "single-sign-on" across different clientIds (i.e. one per application)...